# Find if a computer is using DHCP or Static through CMD?

Tags: cmd, dhcp, ipconfig

I am looking for a cmd command to return if the currently connected NIC is using a static or DHCP address. DHCP: YES or NO is acceptable.

I think ipconfig might be an option, but I need a way to sort out the DHCP field as well as make sure the field I am pulling is from the correct adapter.

I found this code which will pull out the IP Address, But I have not be able to adjust the code to pull the DHCP status.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr [0-9].\.') do @echo %a | findstr "Address"
```

[image: findstr of IP address]

I tried

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr [0-9].\.') do @echo %a | findstr "DHCP Enabled"
```

and

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr [0-9].\.') do @echo %a | findstr "DHCP"
```

but they return nothing. I think im on the right track, I'm just not sure.

[image: DHCP enabled in one place, but not in another]

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %I in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr /R /C:"^ *IPv4 Address" /C:"^ *DHCP Enabled"') do @echo(%I`. You are first filtering lines containing `Address`, which do no longer include the `DHCP Enabled` lines...

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %a in ('ipconfig /all ^|find "DHCP Enabled"') do echo DHCP:%a
```

Note: dependent on locale (language)
Note: will give you a line for every adapter (without telling you, which adapter)

Comment: Is there a way to make this only show the connected adapter? I need to switch over ~500 computers to a new SSID, but I need to change the IP address if it is static to be within the new range.